# How is AVR Assembly in Eclipse or at Linux command line done?

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm trying to learn AVR development in C and Assembly for the Arduino Uno (Atmel 328p microprocessor) in Linux.

I've found many good guides on how to install and setup the AVR plugin for Eclipse, and I've no problem building and uploading C code. 
However there doesn't seem to be any menu options for creating an assembler project, nor can I seem to find the correct syntax for using the cli avr-as for assembling my programs into a .hex file.

Comment: In some cases you can simply feed a gcc variant with an .S file instead of a .c one and it will figure out what to do with it.  But that depends on having valid assembly files, and a compatible build setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using make, I'd recommend copying the Makefiles from [ChibiOS](http://ChibiOS). For me it works quite well and it's much more aligned to my daily experience with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino IDE and the arduino eclipse plugin support assembly.
Taken from the platform.txt

```
"{compiler.path}{compiler.c.cmd}" {compiler.S.flags} -mmcu={build.mcu} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.S.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
```

compiler.S.flags is empty and so is compiler.S.extra_flags and builds.extra_flags

leaving us with something like

```
avr-gcc -mmcu={build.mcu} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
```

Which is something I think you can handle.